# How to open properties panel?

Tags: interface

I've opened a downloaded file that does not have a properties panel where you can change materials etc. and I don't know how to reopen it. This is the panel I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Easy solution** first: Avoid loading the UI saved in the file, un-check the box shown in the picture below:

[image: load UI in load file option]

Shows the top right corner of the open file browser.

Click on the little cogwheel/options icon and you can un-check the "Load UI". Results in opening all data but leaving your User Interface untouched.

**Longer solution** for completeness sake:

If you have no properties and outliner area, you can hover with your mouse over the separation between the 3D View and the Menu, as they are essentially 2 different areas. Your mouse will turn into the 2 sided arrow and you can right click and select "vertical split", then split the 3D View where you want the new area to start. After that you can do the same again along the line separating the 2 areas and this time split horizontal. Afterwards you can simply switch each area to which ever type you want.

Easier to understand visually:

[image]

Comment: Really helpful, thank you.